# Empty JSON Object check

Tags: jquery, json, isnullorempty

When I console print I get value of var a as Object{}, which is empty JSON Object
Using jQuery how do I check for the empty value?
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the jQuery function:

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject( object )
```

More detailed description here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/

EDIT: 
As I always say... and insist on it. Rule number one of the programmer:

"Man pages are your best friend" or the one I was slapped with in school "F1 is there for a reason"