# How to test for empty JSON object?

Tags: json, parsing, delphi

**Scenario**

I use the JsonDataObjects unit by Andreas Hausladen in various places in my Delphi 2009 project, and now I have a requirement to parse the simple JSON returned by an API call to cpanel on a remote server.

Most of it I can do, but the JSON returned in this case appears, at least at the moment, to have an empty object `{}` (not one that is null), and I would appreciate some help (a) testing for an empty object, and (b) obtaining some values from the object if it is not empty.

**The data**

The cpanel API documentation [here](https://api.docs.cpanel.net/openapi/cpanel/operation/add_host/) says that the returns JSON has the form below where metadata is empty.

```json
{
   "apiversion": 3,
   "func": "add_host",
   "module": "Mysql",
   "result": {
      "data": null,
      "errors": null,
      "messages": null,
      "metadata": { },
      "status": 1,
      "warnings": null
   }
}
```

In fact, the documentation is wrong and the data I get back has this form, i.e. there is no `results` object. However, the `metadata` object is still empty, as in the documentation. I don't know what it will look like if the `metadata` object is ever not empty. The documentation doesn't say.

```json
{                                   
   "data":"MyData",                    
   "errors":["The first error text"],  
   "warnings":null,                    
   "status":0,                         
   "messages":null,                    
   "metadata":{}                       
}
```

**The questions**

1. How do I test for the object `MainObj['metadata']` being empty? It isn't `null` as it contain `{}`, so `If MainObj['metadata'].isnull ...` returns false, and the code drops into the `else` part.
2. Once I have tested for it being empty, how do I extract the object's data (which presumably **is** null) when it doesn't have a name?

**The problem code**

This is a small test procedure to demonstrate my problem parsing this data. Most lines produce the expected result. The issue is with the object `MainObj['metadata']`, which is (currently) empty in the JSON.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
const 
  THEJSON =  ''
    +' {                                   '
    +' "data":"MyData",                    '
    +' "errors":["The first error text"],  '
    +' "warnings":null,                    '
    +' "status":0,                         '
    +' "messages":null,                    '
    +' "metadata":{}                       '
    +' }                                   ';    
var
  MainObj, MetaDataObject: TJsonObject;
  i : Integer;
begin
  MainObj := TJsonObject.Parse(THEJSON) as TJsonObject;
  try
    if MainObj['data'].IsNull then
      Memo2.Lines.Add('data = NULL')
    else
      Memo2.Lines.Add('data = ' + MainObj['data'].value);
    if MainObj['warnings'].IsNull then
      Memo2.Lines.Add('warnings = NULL')
    else
      Memo2.Lines.Add('warnings = ' + MainObj['warnings'].value);
    if MainObj['status'].IsNull then
      Memo2.Lines.Add('status = NULL')
    else
      Memo2.Lines.Add('status = ' + MainObj['status'].value);
    if MainObj['messages'].IsNull then
      Memo2.Lines.Add('messages = NULL')
    else
      Memo2.Lines.Add('messages = ' + MainObj['messages'].value);
    if MainObj['errors'].IsNull then
      Memo2.Lines.Add('errors = NULL')
    else
      for I := 0 to MainObj['errors'].count - 1 do
        Memo2.Lines.Add('Error' + IntToStr(i) + ' = ' + MainObj['errors'].items[i]) ;
    
    if MainObj['metadata'].isnull then
      Memo2.Lines.Add('metadata = No object')
    else
    begin
      //this is where it goes pear shaped!
      MetaDataObject := TJsonObject.Parse(MainObj['metadata']) as TJsonObject;   //cannot cast object to string???
      try
        Memo2.Lines.Add('metadata text is ' + MetaDataObject.ToString);
        if MetaDataObject['????].isnull then   / if MetaDataObject['????] is empty then   //what goes here?
          Memo2.Lines.Add('metadata = NULL')
        else                    '
          Memo2.Lines.Add('metadata = ' + MetaDataObject.Value);
      finally
        MetaDataObject.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    MainObj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Expected result**

```
data = MyData
warnings = NULL
status = 0
messages = NULL
Error0 = The first error text
```

followed by

```
metadata text is {}
metadata = NULL
```

Or, if there is data there, followed by

```
metadata text is {"meta_1":"mymeta"}
metadata = mymeta
```

**Actual results**

```
data = MyData
warnings = NULL
status = 0
messages = NULL
Error0 = The first error text
```

followed by a runtime error 'cannot cast object to string'.

**What I have tried**

```pascal
if not Assigned(MetaDataObject) then ...
```

```pascal
if not Assigned(MainObj['metadata']) then ...
```

```pascal
if Assigned (TJsonObject(MainObj['metadata'])) then
  MetaDataObject := TJsonObject.Parse(MainObj['metadata']) as TJsonObject;
```

**Where I have looked**

[JSON specification for empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714718/json-specification-for-empty-objects)

[Empty JSON Object check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432475/empty-json-object-check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to access child values from a JSON object.

The `TJsonObject.Count` property will be 0 when a JSON object is non-null but has no child values (ie, is empty).  So, first check if the desired value is `null`, and if not then access the value as a `TJsonObject` and check if its `Count` is 0, and act accordingly.

For example:

```
if MainObj.IsNull('metadata') then
  Memo2.Lines.Add('metadata = No object')
else
begin
  MetaDataObject := MainObj.O['metadata'];
  if MetaDataObject.Count = 0 then
    Memo2.Lines.Add('metadata = empty')
  else
    Memo2.Lines.Add('metadata text is ' + MetaDataObject.ToString);
end;
```

Comment: Still have problems. Using  
`if MainObj['metadata'].isnull then
      Memo2.Lines.Add('metadata = No object')
  else
      begin
      if MainObj['metadata'].count = 0 then
         Memo2.Lines.Add('metadata is empty')
      else
         Memo2.Lines.Add('metadata = ' + MainObj['metadata'].Value);
      end;`
gives 'cannot cast object into array' on the line `if MainObj['metadata'].count = 0 `

Comment: You need to cast `MainObj['metadata']` to `TJsonObject` before accessing its `count`.  The `TJsonObject.Values[]` property (which `MainObj['...']` is calling) returns a `TJsonDataValueHelper`, and `TJsonDataValueHelper.count` only works for arrays, not objects (design issue?), so you need to access `TJsonObject.Count` instead.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it Remy! I posted my comment and then thought 'I bet I need to cast that first' Got it working just as I saw your comment. So, who is going to post a fully correct answer?

Comment: I already stated as much in my answer above: "*if [not null] then access the value **as a `TJsonObject`** and check if its `Count` is 0...*" But I will add an example for you...

Comment: Opps, Sorry Remy, I didn't notice the answer was from you. - too keen to try out the suggestion. Thank you. Accepted